# Cleaving and inserting a token

Tags: python, python-2.7, split

CONTEXT:

```
myString = "Athletes like baseball and basketball"
tokens = myString.split()
tokens
['Athletes', 'like', 'baseball', 'and', 'basketball']
```

QUESTION: is there a clever & elegant command that directs the third token string to be cleaved at position 4 into two tokens such that the result is

```
>>> tokens
['Athletes', 'like', 'base', 'ball', 'and', 'basketball']
```

The cleaving mechanism should be performed on the basis of the position (i.e. four characters from right)

Bonus for concatenating base + ball and restoring the array back to 5 elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find

```
tokens = tokens[:2] + [tokens[2][:4], tokens[2][4:]] + tokens[3:]
```

elegant enough. And the inverse:

```
tokens = tokens[:2] + [tokens[2] + tokens[3]] + tokens[4:]
```

Comment: This does the splitting on the basis of the position four characters from the *left*, but the OP asks for four characters from the *right*. That is the same thing for the given example but would fail if the third string has a length other than 8. The correction is easy: could you do it?

Comment: @everybody, if you decide to comment and perform the splitting from the right, please add and do not delete the original code coming from the left.  I think there is significant value having examples from left and right processing.

Comment: To split 4 characters from the right, use -4 in place of 4.

Comment: This seems like a golden opportunity  (begging) for a function: splittoken(array, tokenIndex,  numCharacters, fromLeft\Right).  Thanks to all the constructive responses